# No access control allow origin ionic project with java rest backend

Tags: javascript, rest, tomcat, ionic-framework, jax-ws

I am trying to access my java backend through my ionic application, but i receive the following error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/mybackend/rest/.... No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I did this configuration:
http://ionicinaction.com/blog/how-to-fix-cors-issues-revisited/

But still not working.

I'm testing this with `ionic serve` in a browser.

Comment: You are going to need to provide more information. How are you serving the app. Are you hitting the proxied endpoints I your front end code?

Comment: Robert, I am doing $http.get( myurl) using angularjs and in my backend i did the implementation using javax.ws and hibernate for persintence.

Comment: Can you pleas tell us *how* you're testing this? Are you developing in your browser? Or are you getting these errors when testing on a real device after you've packaged & deployed it onto a real device or emulator?

Comment: i am testing in browser using ionic serve command for while mhx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making the assumption that you are running the built in ionic server which starts on port 8100. If you are using the proxy setup described in the link,  then you should be hitting your api end points against

http://localhost:8100/mybackend/rest/..

You appear to be directly hitting the java app (often on port 8080). If you want to hit your api server directly, then you need to set up CORS on the java/spring side. Doing that is plenty well documented.

Otherwise you need to configure the api url for the angular $http service. To use the proxy, you must hit port 8100.

Comment: exactly Robert, i am running my ionic app in browser (in 8100 port) for while (because is better to debbug javascript) and my backend is running in 8080. And i fixed the url into my angular controller like: $http.get('http://localhost:8080/myService/rest/user/list')

Comment: Psychic debugging!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little bit vague, like how are you testing this? What device?
I suppose it must be one of the following 2 situations:

1. Testing in your browser (ex: Google Chrome)
   Since you're developing on localhost, you may get these so called CORS-erros.
   A simple solution for Google Chrome, would be installing a plugin which handles this.
   Install the Google Chrome [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=nl) extension.
   Now your calls won't throw errors hopefully.
2. Testing on an emulator or a real device after a deploy/build

> If you're using a newer version of Cordova (or the latest Ionic CLI) to develop your app, you may be experiencing http 404 errors when your app tries to make network requests.

This can be solved quickly with [Cordova Whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist).

You can find more documentation on [Ionic docs: Cordova Whitelist](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/cordova-whitelist).

**Solution:**

Run the following command in your shell/terminal:

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
```

The only thing you need to do now is to add a property to your `config.xml`
 file:

`<allow-navigation href="*" />`

Comment: I am testing on browser, and i am going to run the app on nexus 4. I am going to follow your solution mhx, tks

Comment: I tried to install the plugin and put the put the tag <allow-navigation href="*" /> into my config file.